# set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0 if you are not a googler

Tags: open-source, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Can someone explain how being a "googler" or not affects how an open source package builds or not?

When attempting to build v8 the [build docs](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building%20with%20Gyp) state

```
"If you are a non-googler you need to set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0"
```

When I set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN to 0 as a "non googler" the build cuts short.
When I set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN to 1 as a "googler" the build doesn't cut short but errors out later on in a way that *points to requiring a specific hash value on the build system*.

When inquiring about the error on the googlegroup v8-users an employee of google stated:

> "It wouldn't enter this code if the environment variable I mentioned 
>   was set correctly. If you do enter this code it's  not set. And it is
>   expected to fail"

Which means the build is expected to fail for "non googlers".

He goes on to say that the build platform I'm on is not supported (non googler, no hash value...) yet that "it should compile at least".

?

Can someone explain how "*it should compile at least*" ?

If you are a "non googler" do you use another build script and build tools ? Possibly get the source otherwise and use different parameters ? Do you even attempt to build the package at all (in the sense that "non googlers" are not meant to build the package)?

If anyone has some experience here it would be helpful as it would save a lot of time and trouble for people trying to build packages with 
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0 if you are not a googler

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't built V8, but one way you could approach this is to set up a VM (using VirtualBox, for example) and run the build off of an OS with better support.

Comment: I ran into this (non-googler) and it simply works if you set it to 0.   I'd suggest that trying to understand their build system isn't worth it for most people.  Once it builds, for most people, it doesn't matter anymore.  You've got your libs and now the 'fun' begins :)

Comment: @xaxxon. setting it to 0 stops it short. the google employee states that's intended. another platform would most likely encounter the same issues since the issue is about being a googler or non googler(I added some emphasis to the question to make that clearer)

Comment: Not sure.   Worked for me about 3 months ago last time I did a windows build.

Comment: That block quote is an actual quote. "expected to fail". It's also exactly what happens. If you set it to 1 or ignore it, it looks for  hash value on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly be able to build V8. You do not need access to any special infrastructure or tooling. There are many V8 committers that are not Google employees.

That particular environment variable `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN` is different for Google employees because of licensing reasons (distributing Microsoft toolchain via `depot_tools`), but you can build V8 with and without that variable.